# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'platformdirs<3,>=2' distribution was not found and is required by virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create an isolated environment using pip, the instructions from "Hands on Machine Learning With Ski-Kit and Tensor Flow" have me run these lines of code and this is the output I get. I've tried uninstalling `pipenv` and that creates another error where pipenv command not found.  Not sure how to work around this, can anyone help?  I'm using a Mac with python3.9

Darrens-MacBook-Air:~ odonned4$ `cd $ML_PATH`

Darrens-MacBook-Air:~ odonned4$ `virtualenv env`

````
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'platformdirs<3,>=2' distribution was not found and is required by virtualenv```
````

Answer (score 8):

### What is the problem?

You are trying to run Python 3.9, right? Well, according to your error message, it seems like you're invoking Python 2.7:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
                                                           ^^^
```

This confusion happens because macOS added Python 2.7 to the distribution for... compatibility reasons. And, probably, you have `virtualenv` on that distribution, but you don't have `platformdirs`, so creating a virtualenv fails.

### How to solve the problem?

There are many ways to clarify this confusion. A good way is using `python3 -m virtualenv` (instead of `virtualenv`). That should create a virtualenv with Python 3.

Also, you can get sure that the `virtualenv` package is available in your Python 3.9 installation. To identify that, see if `virtualenv` appears when typing `python3 -m pip list`. If not, run `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem here is that Mac is hard wired to use `python2`. When using `virtualenv`, you might have run the command:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv
```

which should have added `virtualenv` to the `/usr/bin/` for direct use, but to be used with the default `python2` instead of `python3.9` which you might have installed on your own.

A simple way around is to use

```sh
$ python3 -m virtualenv <env-name>
```

instead of

```sh
$ virtualenv <env-name>
```

Or in my case, add an alias in `.bash_profile`:

```sh
$ alias virtualenv="python3 -m virtualenv"
```

which is a duct tape solution but it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling `setuptools` with

```
pip uninstall -y setuptools
```

and reinstalling it with

```
pip install setuptools
```

**OR**

Upgrade setuptools with

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

**OR**

For me i have faced this issue some before in python 3.8.
I fixed it by

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools
```

**OR**

Uninstall virtualenv and setuptools first and find pip cache folder.

```
pip cache dir
```

Delete the cache and install virtualenv and setuptools.

***I JUST SAID SOME STEPS .. TRY THIS . MAY HELP : )***